# how to read excel files datas and write into csv file using java?

Tags: java, excel, csv, jakarta-ee

could you please anyone assist me how to read excel files datas and write into  csv file using java????

Please give Code for this scenario

Thanks in Advance

Regards
Kumar

Comment: I don't understand how it is duplicate. The question which is duplicate to this says - Read and write excel. Here question is read excel and write csv using java

Comment: You can find answer here: http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/converting-xls-to-csv-files-using-java/

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to convert your excel file into a .CSV file by saving it as such. Then you could, depending on the excel table structure, read the CSV file if the table successfully saved as one.

I think reading a simple CSV-file in Java won't require any sample-coding from me since it is fairly simple if one understands the I/O operations of the Java API.

If you actually need to do that converting manually I would not go for Java here. Use VBA which is used for macro programming in Excel.

Comment: Actually i have a task to do Read a Excel file fields and Write into CSV files

Comment: Actually i have a task to do Read a Excel file fields and Write into CSV files Using Java only. kindly suggest on this...